# Best practice: handling actions from buttons inside tableview cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a "contact list" table view with "contact" cells that contain an email button that, when tapped, should present an email composer with the email address of that contact.

What is the best way to associate the UIButton with the "contact" instance of that cell?

I’ve created answers for the two approaches that come to mind – but which I don’t really find satisfactory. Which do you prefer, or much better still, suggest better ones!

Answer (score 15):

#### Approach 2:

Make the cells handle the action and call a custom delegate method.

```
// YMContactCell.h
@protocol YMContactCellDelegate
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
@end

@interface YMContactCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<YMContactCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

// YMContactCell.m
- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate contactCellEmailWasTapped:self];
}

// ContactListViewController.m
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    YMContact *contact = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // present composer with `contact` ...
}
```

Doesn’t handling events in a view violate the MVC principle?

Comment: I have some just like you, but my "IBAction" inside ViewCell.m is not firing.

Comment: Don't forget set `cell.delegate=self` in `ContactListViewController .m`.

Comment: Also don't forget to add the delegate to the interface: `@interface ContactListViewController () <YMContactCellDelegate>`

Answer (score 7):

The way I most often see it done is by assigning tags to the buttons that are equal to the indexPath.row.

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.theLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}



-(void)doSomething:(UIButton *) sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.theData[sender.tag]);
    //sender.tag will be equal to indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: This seems limited if there are multiple sections.

Comment: @Samuel, it there are multiple section, then you just assign the tags with something like tag = indexPath.section*100 + indexPath.row

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for your suggestion. However, this seems fragile: what if a section has 100+ rows? what if some other view e.g. in a custom control from an open-source library decided to use the exact same tag?

Comment: @Yang, well I don't know, how about section * 1000 instead? Use whatever multiplier you need for your situation. As far as a custom control, it wouldn't matter if it had the same tag, because it wouldn't have the same action method.Only your buttons are calling doSomething:

Comment: Warning if you have Empty Section ! section number will be wrong

Comment: I've encountered this problem a few times. I'd say this is the best solution if you really do need a button on your UITableViewCell, however from an UI/UX perspective, try to avoid having buttons on cells if at all possible. Cells are flexible controls, but having two or more actions taken when clicking inside a cell (say one on @selector(didSelectRowAtIndex:) and one when the button is pressed) can confuse the user in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

**Another solution:**

For me something like this works flawlessly, and looks very elegant:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
      CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                       toView:self.tableView];
      NSIndexPath *clickedIP = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

      // When necessary 
      // UITableViewCell *clickedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:clickedIP];
}
```

**Update 12/01/2017**

After some time, and implementing lots of UITableViews, I need to admit that the best solution is using the delegation pattern, already suggested by others here.

Comment: Upvote based on your update. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

Reading these answers, i would like say my opinion:

### Cell by button position

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
  CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *clickedIP = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

  // When necessary 
  // UITableViewCell *clickedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:clickedIP];
}
```

the solution above is certainly the **most rapid to implement**, but **it is not the best from the  point of view of the design/architecture**. Moreover you obtain the `indexPath` but need to calculate any other info. This is a cool method, but would say not the best.

### Cell by while cycle on the button superviews

```
// ContactListViewController.m

- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    YMContact *contact = [self contactFromContactButton:sender];
    // present composer with `contact`...
}

- (YMContact *)contactFromContactButton:(UIView *)contactButton {
    UIView *aSuperview = [contactButton superview];
    while (![aSuperview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        aSuperview = [aSuperview superview];
    }
    YMContactCell *cell = (id) aSuperview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    return [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Get the cell in this way is more expensive of the previous and it is not elegant as well.

### Cell by button tag

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.theLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void)doSomething:(UIButton *) sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.theData[sender.tag]);
    //sender.tag will be equal to indexPath.row
}
```

Absolutely no. Use the tag can seems a cool solution, but the **tag of a control can be used for a lot of things**, like the next responder etc. I don't like and this **is not the right way**.

### Cell by design pattern

```
// YMContactCell.h
@protocol YMContactCellDelegate
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
@end

@interface YMContactCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<YMContactCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

// YMContactCell.m
- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate contactCellEmailWasTapped:self];
}

// ContactListViewController.m
- (void)contactCellEmailWasTapped:(YMContactCell*)cell;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    YMContact *contact = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // present composer with `contact` ...
}
```

**This is the solution**. Use `delegation` or use `blocks` is really a nice thing to do because **you can pass all parameters that you want and make the architecture scalable**. In fact in the `delegate` method (but also with `blocks`) you could want send directly informations without having the need to calculate them later, like the previous solutions.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on the existing answers. For the future, consider commenting on the existing answers with, well, a comment.

Answer (score 3):

### Swift Closure Approach

I guess I found a new approach which is a bit swifty. Tell me what you think about it.

#### Your Cell:

```
class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {
    var buttonAction: ( () -> Void)?
    
    func buttonPressed() {
       self.buttonAction?()
   }
}
```

#### Your UITableViewDataSource:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CallCell", for: indexPath)
         //Handled inside 
         cell.buttonAction = {
            //Button pressed 
         }
         //Handle in method
         cell.buttonAction = self.handleInnerCellButtonPress() 
 }
```

You can also pass data inside this call. Like the cell or something stored inside the cell.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach 1:

Determine the cell, and thence the index path, by traversing the cell’s view hierarchy from the button.

```
// ContactListViewController.m

- (IBAction)emailContact:(id)sender {
    YMContact *contact = [self contactFromContactButton:sender];
    // present composer with `contact`...
}

- (YMContact *)contactFromContactButton:(UIView *)contactButton {
    UIView *aSuperview = [contactButton superview];
    while (![aSuperview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        aSuperview = [aSuperview superview];
    }
    YMContactCell *cell = (id) aSuperview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    return [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

It feels clunky to me. Kinda "meh"…

Answer (score 0):

I would provide another approach, just doesn't assign the active target, the event will traverse upon the responder chain:

```
[self.actionButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(onActionButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then, in your view controller:

```
- (void)onActorButtonClick:(id)sender {
  if ([sender isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self findAncestorTableCell:(UIView *)sender]; //See other answer to fetch the cell instance.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.listTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    ...
  }
}
```

However, this begets some compiler warning, add this to ignore them:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```